# Generating an arithmetic overflow

Tags: c

Why these two values produces zero output. I thought it suppose to generate an arithmetic overflow but acting like a and b have opposite signes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
// trying to generate an arithmetic overflow
int sum(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
int main()
{
    int a=2147483648;
    int b=2147483648;
    printf("%d", sum(a,b));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, it's *Undefined Behavior* resulting from integer overflow - anything can happen. Compiling with warnings enabled provides `"overflow.c:8:5: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]"` and at `"overflow.c:9:5 ..."`

Comment: Undefined behavior or not, `2147483648 + 2147483648 = 4294967296 = 2^32 = 0 (mod 2^32)` assuming a 32-bit integer.

Comment: [C11 Standard - 3.4.3(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3p3) - `"EXAMPLE An example of undefined behavior is the behavior on integer overflow."` (how each individual compiler handles that condition is not defined - but assigning `0` as a result would be one reasonable way -- there is just no guarantee how it will be handled)

Comment: `int a=2147483648;` causes implementation-defined behaviour (if int is 32-bit) since the initializer is out of range for `int`

Comment: @ybungalobill your logic is invalid as if it is a 32-bit integer then there cannot be `2147483648` in the first place

Comment: @M.M there is, [modulo 2^32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).

Comment: @ybungalobill there's no modulo operation in this code

Answer (score 1):

For your specific compiler on your specific computer; it's plausible that `int a=2147483648;` is essentially the same as `int a=INT_MAX+1;` which is treated like `int a=INT_MIN;`, and same for `int b`, and that this leads to `return INT_MIN+INT_MIN;` which is actually like "0x80000000 + 0x80000000 = 0x100000000 = 0x00000000 with overflow".

However, all of the above relies on undefined behavior (with the assumption that the undefined behavior accidentally causes wrapping in practice).

In general; you want to use `unsigned int` (or even better, `uint32_t`) to avoid undefined behavior and get the "intended overflow" you were hoping for.